# Clear search bar using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using selenium to check if FB pages exist. When i enter the page title in the search bar it works fine but after the second loop the name of the page gets attached to the preview search and i cant find a way to clear the previous search.

For example it looks for
xyz for the first time
then it looks for
xyzabc when i just want to look for abc this time.

How can i clear the search bar so i can just enter the input without the previous input?
Here is my code

```
   for page_target in df.page_name.values:
        time.sleep(3) 
        inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        inputElement.send_keys(page_target)
        inputElement.submit()
        time.sleep(5) 
    
        html = driver.page_source
    
        soup  = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').get_text()
        title = soup.find(page_target)
    
        #if page exists add 1 to the dic otherwise -1
        if title > 0:
            dic_holder[page_target] = 1
        else:
            dic_holder[page_target] = -1
            
        driver.find_element_by_name("q").clear()
        
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Maybe clear before `send_keys`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use
WebElement.clear();//to clear the previous search item
WebElement.sendkeys(abc);//to insert the new search

Also I guess you have a sticky search in your application hence I recommend you to use this method everytime you insert something in the searchbox

Comment: whats a sticky search?

Comment: Sticky boxes are boxes that stay visible on your browser no matter where you scroll on the page

Answer (score 0):

Few ways to do it:

1. Use `element.clear()`. I see that you already tried in your code, not sure how it didn't work but I guess it is not text box or input element?
2. Use javascript: `driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("q")[0].value=""');`
3. Emulate Ctrl+A?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
elem.send_keys("page 1")
```